# Does my database design work? Newbie!

Tags: database-design

I've uploaded an image of my database design below. This is the first database I have designed and I was hoping that I could get some input into whether or not it is set up correctly or if I just have no idea what I'm doing! I am using MySQL. It is for an rpg game. Thanks so much for your time.

Overview of what it should do:

- Each user should be able to own multiple characters,
- But each character should be owned by only one user
- Each Character should have only one location
- But many Characters can exist in one location
- Each character should own one container (inventory)
- But each container should only belong to one character/NPC (a container cannot be owned by both a character and an NPC)
- Each container may or may not have only one location
- But one location can have many containers inside of it
- Each item/weapon/armor should either exist inside of one container or have one location
- But one container or location can have many item/weapon/armor
- Each NPC should have one location
- But one location can have many NPC

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Each user should be able to own multiple characters
>
> But each character should be owned by only one user

Then there is no need for `user_character`. A foreign key column in `character` would suffice.

I'd suggest you roll `character` and `npc` into the one table, perhaps with a flag to distinguish.  This will save a lot of duplication and `UNION` statements later.

Combine all the item/ weapon/ armour into a single `item` table, perhaps with a foreign key from an `item_type` table. This will remove a lot of complication, too.

Comment: Yes. Note that NPC is Non Player CHARACTER - so you can say a NPC is a character with... no player ;) This will make a lot of things easier - also down the road with logic. You POSSIBLY could do the same with location and container.

Comment: thanks for the advice! those sound like great ideas to implement. It is a bit over complicated in it's present state